# Rubocop: Call super to initialize state of the parent class even when super class doesn't have initialization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubocop

Out of nowhere, Rubocop is complaining about classes that are not calling super.

```sh
W: Lint/MissingSuper: Call `super` to initialize state of the parent class.
```

Example:

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

class ApplicationService
  class << self
    def call(*args)
      new(*args).call
    end
  end

  def initialize(_args)
    raise NotImplementedError
  end

  def call
    raise NotImplementedError
  end
end
```

```rb
class SampleService < ApplicationService
  def initialize(something)
    @something = something
  end

  def call
   # do something
  end

  private

  # remaining methods
end
```

I have `ApplicationService` just as a way to easily call a service with: `SampleService.call(arguments)`.

Comment: Is the class inherited?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] of the problem. Rubocop would not complain about anything in the code you have provided. My **guess** (!!!!) is that in reality, `TestService` inherits from a base class, and rubocop is complaining the `TestService#initialize` does not call `super`, because that's how you would generally expect a sub-class to behave. Is that the case? In which case again I'll ask, can you please provide a code sample that actually reproduced the problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For the services you could set in .rubocop.yml:

```yaml
Lint/MissingSuper:
  Exclude:
    - 'app/services/**/*'
```

source: [Recommend calling super in initialize](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide/issues/809)

Comment: Interesting how this example is almost identical: https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide/issues/809#issuecomment-673096138